# Magento 2 : Integrate DPD Shipping Carrier - Where to find test credentials?

Tags: magento2, shipping

I am trying to integrate DPD shipping carrier in my Magento UK site. I am creating a custom module for this as the shipping carrier does not come integrated out of the box in Magento.

I'd like to know from where do I get the sandbox/test credentials for authenticating while connecting to the DPD shipping API? The DPD site doesn't let me register for the same.

Any links pointing to resources/guidance regarding this would be most welcome :)